# Difference between a read and load

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

What is the major difference between read and load and write and store?

I know it is a very basic question, but somehow I'm not able to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is usually associated reading data from a permanent storage (HDD, USB Stick etc.).
`load` on the other hand is *loading* data you have previously read from RAM into a CPU register/accumulator (Assembly command `lda`).

The same goes for `write`, which means *writing* data to a permanent storage.
And `store`, which *stores* values of a register/accumulator to a variable in RAM to save its value.

Comment: Read and write are not restricted to *"permanent storage"*. You can read and write a peripheral's control registers (which are volatile) as well as read/write RAM.

Comment: @sawdust this is why have written "usually". I know you can read from *any* data source (all inputstreams) and write to *any* data output (all outputstreams).

Answer (score 6):

> What is the major difference between and read and load and a write and store?

An answer is complicated because these words could be used as jargon as well as used in a conventional manner in a technical document.  Even as jargon the meanings of these verbs can depend on the context of their use.

A key concept is that the direction of data transfers within a computer are (almost) always relative to the CPU.  An *input* is a data transfer directed towards the CPU.  An *output* is a data transfer directed away from the CPU.

The differences of *read* versus *load* and *write* versus *store* relate primarily to the object of the action.  The object of a *read* is the source of the data transfer (e.g. you *read* (from) memory or *read* (from) a device register or *read* a book). "*Read* into memory" is awkward grammar/semantics.  The object of a *load* is the destination of the data transfer (e.g. you *load* a register or *load* (into) memory or *load* a cart).  Both *read* and *load* can be input operations, but *read* focuses on the source of that input whereas *load* focuses on the destination of that transfer.

Similarly the object of a *write* is the destination of the data transfer (e.g. you *write* (to) memory or *write* (to) a device register).  "*Write* from memory" does not make sense.   The object of a *store* is the source of the data transfer (e.g. you *store* a register).  Both *write* and *store* can be output operations, but *write* focuses on the destination of that output whereas *store* focuses on the source of that transfer.

Of course the object of the verbs *read*/*load*/*write*/*store* could also be the data itself, e.g. *read* a *variable* from RAM or *load* a *program*  into memory.  This construct applies to all four verbs, so it's not a difference.

Another concept is that of "destruction".  My first programming teacher drilled into me that "*reads are non-destructive, and writes are destructive*".  He was referring to reading (from) and writing (to) program variables (in memory).  Reading from a variable leaves its value intact.  Writing to a variable destroys its previous value.

*Read*s and *store*s are typically non-destructive; the contents of the source are not modified.  However there are computers that have registers that are cleared when read/stored, and memory locations that increment (or decrement) the contents when read.  *Load*s and *write*s, to make sense, have to be destructive; the data transferred is expected to replace the prior contents at the destination.

Comment: In computer-architecture (CPU design) terminology, it's common to mix load / read almost interchangeably.  I think you might be on to something in your last 2 paragraphs about load being about the destination register, and read being about the memory source, though.  We talk about cache or register-file read/write ports (built into CPU's fast internal storage arrays), but we also talk about load/store execution units (connected to the store-source / load-destination side of thing).  e.g. https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/